# Read using array index in Step Functions

Tags: aws-step-functions

I am getting the following error while executing step functions:-

```
{
  "error": "States.Runtime",
  "cause": "An error occurred while executing the state 'RenameThing' (entered at the event id #9). Invalid path '$.list[$.index]' : com.jayway.jsonpath.InvalidPathException: Could not analyze path component: [$.index]"
}
```

Following is the input: -

```
{
  "name": "RenameThing",
  "input": {
    "list": [
      {
        "xxx": "xxxxx",
        "yyy": "yyyyy",
        "zzz": "zzzz"
      },
      {
        "xxx": "xxxxx2",
        "yyy": "yyyyy2",
        "zzz": "zzzz2"
      }
    ],
    "continue": true,
    "index": 0
  }
}
```

Input path is: -

```
"InputPath":"$.list[$.index]",
```

It seems, aws is not able to find out path [$.index].

Comment: Did you find solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

`$.input.index` will give you the value under `index`

Paste your example here to verify: https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/

Additional reading about [JSONPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath).

[image]

[Context Objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html) for Map may also come handy in the future.

> There are two additional items available in the context object when
> processing a Map state: Index and Value. For each Map state iteration,
> Index contains the index number for the array item that is being
> currently processed, while Value contains the array item being
> processed. Within a Map state, the context object includes the
> following data:

```
"Map": {
   "Item": {
      "Index": Number,
      "Value": "String"
   }
}
```

**Sample**:

```
"Parameters": {
             "ContextIndex.$": "$$.Map.Item.Index",
             "ContextValue.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value"
         },
```